# Finding Taylor Coefficients.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $h:[0,2\pi]\to [a,b]$ be a continuous function of bounded variation and let
$$f(z)=exp\left[\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}h(t)dt\right].$$
Can we say that Taylor coefficients of under bracket function are the Fourier coefficients of $h$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need $h \in H^1$ (no negative powers Fourier coefficients) as you get something like $\hat h(0)+2\sum_{n \ge 1}\hat h(n)z^n$, so the Taylor coefficients are indeed related to the Fourier coefficients of $h$ but only at non-negative integers and with the coefficients as above

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned $h\in H^1$. Thus, in this case the Taylor coefficients function in the bracket are identical with the Fourier coefficients ("related") @Conrad

Comment: not quite as the coefficients are $2$ for $n \ge 1$ so technically they are the Fourier coefficients of $2h-\hat h(0)$

Comment: Indeed! Thanks @Conrad

Comment: happy to be of help